# Laravel processing/redirect after cancelling a modal bootstrap window

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-modal, laravel-5, laravel-blade

In Laravel I have a table that contains an edit link on every row like the following;

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="{{ route('myrow.edit', ['id' => $value['id']]) }}" data-target="#myModal">
    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-pencil"></i>
</a>
```

The modal screen was defined as follows;

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the previously mentioned button is clicked the edit.blade.php included looks like this;

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">My modal title</h4>
</div>
{!! Form::model($myrow, array('route' => array('mycontroller.update', $myrow->id), 'method' => 'PUT')) !!}
    <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- All kinds of fields -->
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The mycontroller.update that was invoked looks like this;

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
        $mymodel = MyModel::find($id);
        $mymodel->user = $request->user()->id;
        $mymodel->field = $request->field;
        if (!$mymodel->save()) {
                    $errors = $mymodel->getErrors();
                    return redirect()
                                ->action('MyController@index')
                                ->with('errors', $errors)
                                ->withInput();
                }
                return redirect()
                    ->action('MyController@index')
                    ->with('message', $mymodel->field . ' was added');
}
```

When I fill in data in my modal screen and submit it all works very well. The problem starts when I either press Cancel, press the "x" that closes the modal or simply click outside of the modal. In those situations the modal will obviously close but when I click an edit link in whatever other row it will always open the modal screen for the previously unsaved row until I refresh the screen.

Apparently I need some processing after the modal window was closed in any way but how should I do that. Does someone have a good strategy for this?

**Update**: it also doesn't perform a second GET request. The first time I click the edit link it retrieves the correct data with
    GET https://example.com/mylaravelapp/mymodel/1/edit
The second (and any subsequent) time no request is made at all.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use JavaScript to clear the form fields and repopulate them depending on the row you clicked. The modal still exists in the Dom after being closed that's why you're seeing the previously entered values

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While checking where and how I should include the Javascript I found out that it also doesn't perform a second GET request. The first time I click the edit link it retrieves the correct data with;
    GET https://example.com/mylaravelapp/mymodel/1/edit
The second (and any subsequent) time no request is made at all. So I'm afraid I don't have any data to update the modal with.

Answer (score 0):

The problem there is with Bootstrap Modal's referencing. You are creating one unique Modal. The button that toggles a Modal uses the `data-target="#myModal"` attribute to reference the html that will popup when you click the button. That part of html is identified by `id="myModal"`. 
So, if you want to create multiple Modals you will need something like this:

- Change **data-target** attribute's value

---

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="{{ route('myrow.edit', ['id' => $value['id']]) }}" data-target="#myModal_{{$value['id']}}">
    <i class="fa fa-btn fa-pencil"></i>
</a>
```

- Then edit the Modal's html definition

---

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal_{{$value['id']}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, you should not create multiples Modals; you must just create only one Modal, and use Javascript to update the Modals content and form's **action** attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While checking where and how I should include the Javascript I found out that it also doesn't perform a second GET request. The first time I click the edit link it retrieves the correct data with;
    GET https://example.com/mylaravelapp/mymodel/1/edit
The second (and any subsequent) time no request is made at all. So I'm afraid I don't have any data to update the modal with.